# Html file displays nul in text editor and shows blank page on browser

Tags: html, character-encoding

I was working on an html file suddenly after restating my laptop when I open the file is brackets it says brackets can only open Utf-8 encoded files, when I open it with N[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc1JR.jpg)otepad++ it shows nul and when I open it with browser it shows a blank page.

Need help

Comment: Maybe your file's now broken?

Comment: If the file is broken, Can I recover?